# Faraday::ConnectionFailed (connection refused: :80)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, faraday

I have created `REST API` in ruby on rails and for api calling I have used 
Faraday as a `REST client`. my application is working totally fine on localhost:3000.

but when I deployed it to heroku it giving me an error

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed (connection refused: :80)
```

Comment: You may need to check the environment config settings. If faraday is trying to connect on port 80, but heroku is using a different port (maybe 8080) then it could be fixed with the proper environment config setting.

Comment: in rails where should i configure that

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/wiki/Setting-up-SSL-certificates#heroku-fedora-centos

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try on port 443.

Comment: You could simply try https instead of http in your URL.

Comment: yes my heroku url is `https` but still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `.env` file in your project which will be holding the port number . You need to configure it and point it to the port where heroku is using .